# How to add an transparent background image in android studio irrespective of transparency of data in the page?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAhCi.png)In linear layout I'm using image view, text view and also the edit text irrespective of the linear layout I'm thinking to add an image in the background which should be transparent when ever I try to use transparency then the whole activity is changing.However,  need only the background image is transparent not the whole page.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Could you show an image of the current result and the desired effect ?

Comment: ive uploaded current image and i just want to put 2 images in activity 1st image as the background image with transparency of 25% and other image will cover half of the page and leaves space for text view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what, I understood........

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/download"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/download"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/dummy_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, your design is not really *appealing*.

In your example, the text is **not readable**, it makes no sense to have an **image twice** in the same screen, the background picture is **stretched** and the front image is so **small**.

I would suggest you use something like this:

[image: Design concept]

If you like it this way, here yo have the XML definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Taj Mahal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#aaaaaa"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/taj_mahal"/>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#aaaaaa"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="The Taj Mahal is an ivory-white marble mausoleum on the south bank of the Yamuna river in the Indian city of Agra. It was commissioned in 1632 by the Mughal emperor, Shah Jahan (reigned 1628–1658), to house the tomb of his favourite wife."
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```